# Gmock function calls are not called

Tags: c++, googlemock

Gmock doesn't work as exected.
EXPECT_CALL doesn't call mock functions.

Here is the code snippet:

In Header.hpp:

```
typedef MockITest ITest;
Class mainclass
{
public:
std::shared_ptr<ITest> mTestCtrl;
funcToTest();
};
```

source.cpp

```
{
std::shared_ptr<mainclass> mainclassPtr;

funcToTest()
{
   mTestCtrl = getCtrl();
   if( nullptr != mTestCtrl){
    cout<< "I can see print here";
      mTestCtrl->start(); 
   }
}
}
```

samplemock.h

```
class MockITest
{
public:
    /// @brief function mock
    MOCK_METHOD0(start, void());
};
std::shared_ptr<MockITest> getCtrl()
{
return std::make_shared<MockITest>();
}
```

test.cpp

```
TEST_F(TestMqttgwProcessKeepAlive, Test_funcToTest)
{
mainclassPtr =  std::make_shared<mainclass>();
mainclassPtr->funcToTest();
EXPECT_CALL(*mainclassPtr->mTestCtrl.get(), start()).Times(1);
}
```

I get this error.
Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
Function call: start()
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mainclassPtr->mTestCtrl.get(), start())...
Expected: to be called once
Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put EXPECT_CALL before the call to `funcToTest`:

```
TEST_F(TestMqttgwProcessKeepAlive, Test_funcToTest)
{
  mainclassPtr =  std::make_shared<mainclass>();

  EXPECT_CALL(*mainclassPtr->mTestCtrl.get(), start()).Times(1);
  mainclassPtr->funcToTest();
}
```

In general, expectations should come first, then calls to the functions that are expected to be called.